# How to order oracle select with passed parameters equal column

Tags: java, oracle

I have function in oracle with returns `sys_refcursor` which is opened for select . I am passing parameter to this oracle function and i will order my select with the column which is equals to this parameter.In example i have 10 column in my select and my parameter may be equals each of them.One condition is to write 10 if clause like this

```
if myParam = 'name' then

select <selected rows>
from table a 
order by a.name
end if;
```

Is there any other condition to be more shortly my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use    [OPEN cursor FOR dynamic_query](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/openfor_statement.htm#LNPLS01333):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_fun( ord VARCHAR2 )
RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
   refcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN refcur FOR 
        'SELECT level as x, 100-level as y  FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
        ORDER BY ' || ord;
    RETURN refcur;
END;
/
```

---

And now:

```
 VAR x REFCURSOR;
 exec :x := my_fun( 'x' );
 print :x;

         X          Y
---------- ----------
         1         99
         2         98
         3         97
         4         96
         5         95
         6         94
         7         93
         8         92
         9         91
        10         90

10 rows selected.
```

---

```
exec :x := my_fun( 'y' );
 print :x;

         X          Y
---------- ----------
        10         90
         9         91
         8         92
         7         93
         6         94
         5         95
         4         96
         3         97
         2         98
         1         99

10 rows selected.
```

---

```
exec :x := my_fun( 'z' );
 print :x;

ORA-00904: "Z": invalid identifier
ORA-06512: "TEST.MY_FUN", line 7
ORA-06512: line 1
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```